# Cmd + a text selection not working on only allowing numeric input at textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser, input

I'm trying to solve a weird issue on Firefox for Mac where I cannot select a text with `CTRL + A` if I only allow numbers as input for a textfield.
I found this fiddle to explain the problem: [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/HkEuf/1/)

Does anyone have an idea why, and how I can solve that?

Comment: if browser shows error message when you press `CTRL + A `, try to add `if (e.ctrlKey && e.which === 97) return true;` to the start of the function

Comment: Any reason why you don't just use the input type number ?

Comment: @EJTH because of crossbrowser!

Comment: @EugenHalca doesn't work neither!

Comment: is the error displayed when `ctrl + a` is pressed ?

Comment: In that case I still wouldn't use your solution, since a user can just right click the field and paste non-numeric characters through there. Instead I guess I would do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Lbgafkz3/

Comment: @EJTH with your solution selection won't work either..

Comment: are you sure you shouldn't use `cmd + a` for these ?

Comment: @EJTH thank you this works, please provide an answer?

Comment: You do know that you could answer it yourself, instead of accepting a bad / wrong answer (Ie. don't even bother doing numeric input with key stroke input, as there is many ways to put content in an input, many ways to do copy+paste across platforms etc.)

Comment: FYI. Updated the fiddle to tweak it. It now responds immediately, so you don't see any non-numeric characters in the input: http://jsfiddle.net/1c6ywyob/

Comment: @EugenHalca You are right about that cmd + a or ctrl + a wouldn't work, I made an updated answer where anything should work fine, as long as it doesn't change input, selection wouldn't be reset. see my answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `metaKey` property of event to find if `cmd` is pressed and pass it without validation.

```
if((e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey) && e.which == 97) {
          return true
      }
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HkEuf/6298/)

Comment: thank you this works fine. Any idea how I could limit this to 5 numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: **don't bother with checking what keys are used to enter the value with**, because there is thousands of ways that user input can end up in a field, which would not fire the keyup/keydown events (voice recognition, copy+paste, hand writing recognition, `$('.foo').val('bar')` from the dev console etc.), and there is many ways to do copy+paste cross platform, so checking for event.ctrlKey + 'c' or similar is a futile battle.

Instead do something like this:

```
function forceNumeric(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]+/gi,''));
}
$('input[type="number"]').on('propertychange input', forceNumeric);
```

This code will strip all non-numeric characters from the input on any input state changing event.